# Adding values to a Report when there is no Data in query SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

I have a query that returns Sales representatives number, Category, Sales.

The result is something like this:

[image]

There are 4 categories called `G1,G2,G3,G4`.

As you can see the Sales representative `11` sold 10 each category (Yellow rows).
But Representative `12` sold only for category `G3` and `G4`.

The idea is to show in the report all the categories and populate with 0 all those who did not sell on that particular category.

It must be grouped by Sales Representative so if you make a tablix grouping by Sales Representatives you will have something like this:

[image]

**But you want something like this:**

[image]

Is there any expression I could use to add these?

What I did so far is to create a group, that group of course are my Sales representatives and combine the cells for that Column and created a Row group for each category, is something like this:

[image]

But if you execute that report it will repeat all categories G1,G2... For each time that category exists for that particular Sales Representative.

Another problem is, how can you evaluate The hardcoded category in your report if it does not exist in your datasource you cant make `Iif("G1" = Fields!Category.Value,Fields!Sales.Value,"0")` as you are not comparing `G1` with `Null` or `IsNothing`, you are comparing what it exists.

Comment: You can evaluate hardcoded using `ReportItems!Textbox1.Value` just replace `textbox1` for the textbox where you hardcoded a value.

Comment: Yes I know but how is it that you can compare something with something that does not exist in your dataset, not only that, how can you avoid the repeating rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve this smoothly using T-SQL at query level. I don't know why you don't use the simplest way to apply this kind of logic since in T-SQL you can use *almost* every logic.

However I like this kind of challenges so I come with this possible solution.

This is my sample dataset:

[image]

In SSRS dataset (not in T-SQL) I've added a calculated field called `Another`

[image]

Another field is set to the below expression:

```
=Fields!SalesRep.Value & "-" & Fields!Category.Value
```

I've added a tablix with the following data arrangement

[image]

As I mentioned before category field is hardcoded, the right column with `Sales`
is set to this expression:

```
=iif(IsNothing(lookup(Fields!SalesRep.Value & "-" & ReportItems!Textbox62.Value,
Fields!Another.Value,Fields!Sales.Value,"DataSet7")),0,
lookup(Fields!SalesRep.Value & "-" & ReportItems!Textbox62.Value,
Fields!Another.Value,Fields!Sales.Value,"DataSet7"))
```

> **Note:** `ReportItems!Textbox62.Value` corresponds to textbox where `G1`
>   was hardcoded. You have to replace the textbox reference for the
>   corresponding in your tablix for every category.

It will preview the below tablix.

[image]

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: You sir, are the man.
Marked as the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Could it be possible to repeat this logic for another Dataset? Both Datasets have the same fields, the difference is that the other Dataset could have, or not the same Sales Rep/Category

Comment: You can use this logic to get Sales for any `Sales Rep - Category` combination. if the `Sales Rep -Category` combination doesn't match dataset values it will return `0` for Sales. If you can't make it works share the new dataset and the desired tablix in other question.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348130/adding-values-to-a-report-when-there-is-no-data-in-query-ssrs-between-datasets