# Adding values to a Report when there is no Data in query SSRS Between Datasets

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

It is basically the same question I had in this thread:
[Adding values to a Report when there is no Data in query SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282098/adding-values-to-a-report-when-there-is-no-data-in-query-ssrs)

The only difference now is that I want to extend the same functionality to different Datasets.

Imagine this:
I have two Datasets. `Dataset1`, `Dataset2`.

Both have the same primary key, in this case:
Sales Rep
Category

Now in Dataset1 I have the following Data:
[image]

The idea in that thread was to put `"0"` Each time a Sales Representative Did not have all the categories, if you see for example Sales Rep on `DataSet1`, does not have `G1,G2` Category so In those cases they have to put 0.

Thanks by the answer of the community this can be achieved by adding a Calculated Field on DataSet1:

```
=Fields!SalesRep.Value & "-" & Fields!Category.Value
```

So that will give you for example `11-G1` for the 1st Row. and the expression for each Row (For each category) will be:

```
=iif(IsNothing(lookup(Fields!SalesRep.Value & "-" & ReportItems!Textbox62.Value,
Fields!Another.Value,Fields!Sales.Value,"DataSet7")),0,
lookup(Fields!SalesRep.Value & "-" & ReportItems!Textbox62.Value,
Fields!Another.Value,Fields!Sales.Value,"DataSet7"))
```

As you can see, the `ReportItems!Textbox62.Value` saves the value of the Category so If 11-G1 is nothing (dont exist) put `"0"`.

The idea here is to do the same thing with `DataSet2`.

The tricky part is that we have to ask if `11-G1` equals `14-G1` because in `DataSet2` the `SalesRep` does not exist for all the categories it must put `"0"`. Both are grouped as `SalesRep`.

Comment: Remember in my answer to your first question, I hardcoded the categories (G1,G2,G3 and G4) then refereced their values by using `ReportItems`. Did you do the same for `dataset 2`?

Comment: I did the same but now we need to ask if both the Calculated fields have the same values or not.

For example if the calculated field Another have the expression:
`Fields!SalesRep.Value & "-" & Fields!Category.Value`

I have to do the same calculated field for the new dataset.

The think is in the example above is finding the same Sales Rep in this case `14-G3` but it needs to compare `11-G1` with `14-G3`

Comment: Let me understand better, you want to find `11-G1` from `DataSet1` in `DataSet2` if it matches return the `DataSet2` `Sales` value. Right?

Comment: Exactly, Both Datasets are grouped by Sales Rep, so for Sales Rep number 11 it should show 0 on Sales in Dataset2.

Comment: Where you want to put the `0` value, maybe `DataSet2` Tablix? A tablix item can be linked to only one dataset, so from `DataSet2` tablix you can lookup on `DataSet1` then in that tablix put the value fetched from `DataSet1`.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to save 0 on Dataset2 Tablix.
If I make a lookup it will bring the 14-G3, Makes sense? because for both Tablix/Datasets 14-G3 exists but it needs to evaluate not the whole dataset but for each row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93376/discussion-between-alejandro-zuleta-and-nickso).