# Adding values to a Report when there is no Data in query SSRS for both Datasets

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

The intro for this little problem starts here:
[Adding values to a Report when there is no Data in query SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282098/adding-values-to-a-report-when-there-is-no-data-in-query-ssrs)

After that:
[Adding values to a Report when there is no Data in query SSRS Between Datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348130/adding-values-to-a-report-when-there-is-no-data-in-query-ssrs-between-datasets)

Now a basic introduction of what Im trying to accomplish.
With this expression:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Lookup(Trim(Fields!total_Cod_vendedor.Value) & "-" & ReportItems!G2.Value, Fields!AgregarMost.Value, Fields!most_atados.Value, "EfectividadDeFrecuencias_Most")) = True, "0", Lookup(Trim(Fields!total_Cod_vendedor.Value) & "-" & ReportItems!G2.Value, Fields!AgregarMost.Value, Fields!most_atados.Value, "EfectividadDeFrecuencias_Most"))
```

What I'm doing is check if the combination of a `Somefield.Value`-`reportitemName.Value` exists on the other `Dataset` where said content is saved in a calculated field inside that other `Dataset`. When the `IsNothing` is `true`, then put a `"0"` if not, `"Dosomething"` which in this case it doesn't matter.

So the idea was to put `0` each time it doesn't exist that combination for the `Dataset` Im right now.

Now, the idea is to do the same but when the other `Dataset` does not have values.

Imagine my tablix have `"Dataset"` where in a certain `Textbox` have that expression but at the same time it could be possible that `"Dataset"` does not have the values that `"Dataset1"` have. I can't Nest Lookups because I was trying to do the following:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Lookup(Trim(Fields!total_Cod_vendedor.Value) & "-" & ReportItems!G1.Value, Fields!AgregarMost.Value, Fields!most_atados.Value, "EfectividadDeFrecuencias_Most")
AND IsNothing(Lookup(Lookup(Trim(Fields!total_Cod_vendedor.Value) & "-" & ReportItems!G1.Value, Fields!AgregarMost.Value, Fields!most_Cod_vendedor.Value, "EfectividadDeFrecuencias_Most") & "-" & ReportItems!G1.Value, Fields!Agregar.Value, Fields!total_atados.Value, "EfectividadDeFrecuencias_Total")
)) = True

, "0"

,Lookup(Trim(Fields!total_Cod_vendedor.Value) & "-" & ReportItems!G1.Value, Fields!AgregarMost.Value, Fields!most_atados.Value, "EfectividadDeFrecuencias_Most"))
```

So to give a more visual example, this was the original Case:
[image]

See how `Dataset2` does not have the same values as `Dataset1` so with this Expression it put 0s where is not Equal that combination (Sales Rep+Category).

Now the idea is to the same thing the other way around, when `Dataset2` have data that `Dataset1` does not have IN THE SAME expression (that means the same textbox where it resides the Tablix which at the same time have the Scope on `Dataset`).

How would you do this?